# Using paypal checkout ot add a user to sql database

Tags: php, sql, paypal

I am trying to create a php file that will be called by paypal checkout and add the persons email and password to an sql database so they can login.

I found a file online but and I made my button send the customer to it.  But I must be doing something wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$password = crypt($_POST['os0']);
if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment

    $table = "checkout";
    include("checkout-config.php");

 // Connect to Mysql Database
mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dblogin","$dbpass");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Unable to select database");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table
(email, password) VALUES ('$_GET[payer_email]', '$password')");

echo "Paid";
//Header( "Location: http://www.rollestonelectric.com/paid.php" );

}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
echo "Unpaid";
//Header( "Location: http://www.rollestonelectric.com/unpaid.php" );

// log for manual investigation
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
```

Comment: For one thing, your first header `$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";` cannot have a dot. Replace it with `$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";`

Comment: Thank you.  I will fix that.  Do you also know a way to have paypal forward customers to this file after checkout?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I'm not well-versed enough with PayPal API.

Answer (score 1):

The file you have found is the IPN listener file.
**IPN : Instant Payment NOtification.**

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that notifies
>   you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use IPN messages
>   to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as
>   fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other
>   transaction-related information.

Yes, you are on right track. To insert the details to sql database after checkout you need to make use of IPN.

`Steps:`

- Turn on the IPN in your Paypal Merchant Account.
- You need to specify
  a IPN return URL , for eg: `www.yourdomain.com/testlistener.php`, where
  `testlistener.php` is your php file you found online in your account.
- A user clicks a PayPal button to kick off a checkout flow; your web application makes an API call; your back-office system makes an API call; or PayPal observes an event.
- PayPal HTTP POSTs your listener an IPN message that notifies you of this event.
  Your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response.
- Your listener HTTP POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to PayPal.
  Note: This message must contain the same fields, in the same order, as the original IPN from PayPal, all preceded by cmd=_notify-validate. Further, this message must use the same encoding as the original.
- PayPal sends a single word back - either VERIFIED (if the message matches the original) or INVALID (if the message does not match the original).

For more help refer this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).